# Can parcolumns be made to expand into the margins?

Tags: margins, parcolumns

I recently started using `parcolumns` instead of block quotes. I do this since I have a non-English source text in the right column and the English translation in the left column.

Is it possible to make `parcolumns` columns eat into the margins of the document, so as to further set them off from the rest of the text?

I tried using the option `colwidths` to try to make the columns larger and force them to eat into the margin equally on either side (for example with the value `colwidths={1=10cm,2=10cm}`). However, this doesn't work; the leftmost column still begin where the left margin ends. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Playing with `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` helps. Negative values allow to write into the margins. Because applies inside the columns, the distance between the columns must be increased by the same amount. The new environment `wideparcolumns` therefore fixes the value for parameter `distance`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newenvironment{wideparcolumns}[1][]{%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{-12mm}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{-12mm}%
  \begin{parcolumns}[%
    distance=\dimexpr-\leftskip-\rightskip+2em\relax,%
    #1%
  ]{2}%
}{\end{parcolumns}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wideparcolumns}
\colchunk{\lipsum[2]}
\colchunk{\lipsum[3]}
\end{wideparcolumns}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]